# Validate a certificate chain (ecdsa)

Tags: openssl, certificate, chain, ecdsa

I need to validate a certificate chain, and I just have the certificates, is that possible?

I'm trying in OpenSSL with the command verify, so when I ran:

```
OpenSSL> verify -CAfile testeroot.cer testesub.cer
```

testesub.cer: OK

However when I try with the ending certificate, I get a error:

```
OpenSSL> verify -CAfile testeroot.cer testesub.cer testeapp.cer
testesub.cer: OK
CN = ecc-crypto-services-encipherment_UC6-InMemory, OU = ApplePay, O = Apple Inc., C = US
error 20 at 0 depth lookup: unable to get local issuer certificate
error testeapp.cer: verification failed
error in verify
```

here is the certificates:

to be validated (the last - testeapp.cer):

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

======================================================================

The intermediate (testesub.cer)

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

======================================================================

the root (CA) - testeroot.cer:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

I've already tried to concatenate the certificates, but it seems that it's just verified the first certificate of the concatenated exit.

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible scenarios we need to consider here.

1) The intermediate certificate is trusted by the verifier

2) The intermediate certificate is not trusted by the verifier

In the first case the intermediate certificate is in the trust store for the verifier. The simplest way to achieve that is to concatenate the root and sub files together:

```
$ cat testeroot.cer testesub.cer >testerootandsub.cer
```

Next we verify like this:

```
$ openssl verify -CAfile testerootandsub.cer testeapp.cer
```

Unfortunately when I try this I get some errors:

```
CN = ecc-crypto-services-encipherment_UC6-InMemory, OU = ApplePay, O = Apple Inc., C = US
error 34 at 0 depth lookup: unhandled critical extension
CN = ecc-crypto-services-encipherment_UC6-InMemory, OU = ApplePay, O = Apple Inc., C = US
error 10 at 0 depth lookup: certificate has expired
error testeapp.cer: verification failed
```

So the first one is an "unhandled critical extension" and the second one is "certificate has expired". Lets look at the certificate:

```
$ openssl x509 -in testeapp.cer -noout -text
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number: 1364869047620188509 (0x12f0fd2adc53b95d)
        Signature Algorithm: ecdsa-with-SHA256
        Issuer: CN = Test Apple Worldwide Developers Relations CA - ECC, OU = Certification Authority, O = Apple Inc., C = US
        Validity
            Not Before: May 20 04:15:57 2017 GMT
            Not After : Jun 19 04:15:57 2019 GMT
        Subject: CN = ecc-crypto-services-encipherment_UC6-InMemory, OU = ApplePay, O = Apple Inc., C = US
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: id-ecPublicKey
                Public-Key: (256 bit)
                pub:
                    04:2e:3e:5c:cf:6b:9a:b0:4b:e7:a2:2f:3f:ac:cf:
                    de:73:c8:7e:87:15:53:94:a3:48:15:40:8a:89:6c:
                    a1:8a:37:4d:ac:66:9a:f3:bf:62:20:fc:86:37:67:
                    f4:af:47:50:7c:5b:c2:21:fc:4a:19:87:4d:af:39:
                    b4:07:4e:3e:b8
                ASN1 OID: prime256v1
                NIST CURVE: P-256
        X509v3 extensions:
            Authority Information Access: 
                OCSP - URI:http://ocsp-uat.corp.apple.com/ocsp04-testwwdrcaecc

            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier: 
                AD:2E:A3:CB:7E:34:C2:ED:EE:43:68:4E:27:11:1F:CC:49:33:39:D0
            X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
                CA:FALSE
            X509v3 Authority Key Identifier: 
                keyid:D6:D6:D5:5A:E5:FF:FD:C2:7C:34:C3:43:DE:BD:68:76:5C:36:A9:BE

            X509v3 Certificate Policies: 
                Policy: 1.2.840.113635.100.5.1
                  User Notice:
                    Explicit Text: Reliance on this certificate by any party assumes acceptance of the then applicable standard terms and conditions of use, certificate policy and certification practice statements.
                  CPS: http://www.apple.com/certificateauthority/

            X509v3 CRL Distribution Points: 

                Full Name:
                  URI:http://crl-uat.corp.apple.com/applewwdrcaecc.crl

            X509v3 Key Usage: critical
                Key Encipherment, Key Agreement
            1.2.840.113635.100.6.39: critical
                ..
    Signature Algorithm: ecdsa-with-SHA256
         30:46:02:21:00:8c:bd:4a:b6:61:4c:58:fd:1a:93:58:4e:05:
         aa:c3:d3:af:dc:c6:ca:29:42:ba:72:14:dc:54:a8:6e:d7:a9:
         ee:02:21:00:de:d5:77:1d:c1:d2:9e:c3:4c:2a:97:1d:dd:39:
         20:fb:19:18:b7:48:0c:6d:4d:4f:13:a4:d8:e8:ff:37:b1:86
```

First we can see that the certificate has indeed expired ("Not After" is "Jun 19 04:15:57 2019 GMT"). Secondly there is a critical extension that OpenSSL does not recognise:

```
            1.2.840.113635.100.6.39: critical
                ..
```

We can get OpenSSL to ignore these two errors like this:

```
$ openssl verify -ignore_critical -no_check_time -CAfile testerootandsub.cer testeapp.cer 
testeapp.cer: OK
```

The second scenario I talked about is where the intermediate certificate is not trusted by the verifier. In this case the verifier is assumed to have the root in their trust store, and the intermediate and end entity certificates will have been supplied to them. In that case the verification command looks like this:

```
$ openssl verify -ignore_critical -no_check_time -CAfile testeroot.cer -untrusted testesub.cer testeapp.cer 
testeapp.cer: OK
```

Comment: Thank u very much